# device tree and led blink

Tags: rpi.gpio, device-tree

I am trying to create one led driver via device tree in Rpi 3
I had created the dtsi file

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;
/ {
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2837";
        fragment@0 {
          target = <&leds>;
          __overlay__ {
            driver_01: led {
              label = "led17";
              gpios = <&gpio 17 0>;
            };
          };
        };
};
```

And included in bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dts adding `#include <led_drv.dtsi>` to it
The location for dts is `linux-rpi-4.9.y/arch/arm64/boot/dts/broadcom$`

For the sake of checking, i just did

```
../../../../../scripts/dtc/dtc -@ -I dts -O dtb -o test.dtb bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dts
```

before adding my own dtsi file
But it showed Error:

```
bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dts:2.1-9 syntax error
FATAL ERROR: Unable to parse input tree
```

Remember this is before adding anothing, just the downloaded source from official rpi git account

I am a bit confused due to this. Also am I correct on the arm64 part? at arm /... dir, there is no rpi 3 dts, but in arm64  rpi3 dts is there.

However if I do :

```
../../../../../scripts/dtc/dtc -@ -I dts -O dtb -o led_drv.dtbo led_drv.dtsi
```

The result shows `Warning (unit_address_vs_reg): Node /fragment@0 has a unit name, but no reg property`

But it generates the .dtbo file.

I studied different tutorials , but things are not clear yet. Any suggestion? Not getting the clear view and confused.